# Insert csrf token for file upload

Tags: javascript, django

How to insert csrf token in [LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader](https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader)?

I tried with `customHeaders` but without success.
Although, `$("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()` gives `qEN1kNfYYkAasfqBn3AigICJmz4MIlei`

```
var uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
        button: btn,
        url: 'file_upload/',
        name: 'uploadfile',
        customHeaders: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()
        },
        multipart: true,
        hoverClass: 'hover',
        focusClass: 'focus',
        responseType: 'json',
        startXHR: function() {
            progressOuter.style.display = 'block'; // make progress bar visible
            this.setProgressBar( progressBar );
        },
        onSubmit: function() {
            msgBox.innerHTML = ''; // empty the message box
            btn.innerHTML = 'Uploading...'; // change button text to "Uploading..."
          },
        onComplete: function( filename, response ) {
            btn.innerHTML = 'Choose Another File';
            progressOuter.style.display = 'none'; // hide progress bar when upload is completed
            if ( !response ) {
                msgBox.innerHTML = 'Unable to upload file';
                return;
            }
            if ( response.success === true ) {
                msgBox.innerHTML = '<strong>' + escapeTags( filename ) + '</strong>' + ' successfully uploaded.';
            } else {
                if ( response.msg )  {
                    msgBox.innerHTML = escapeTags( response.msg );
                } else {
                    msgBox.innerHTML = 'An error occurred and the upload failed.';
                }
            }
          },
        onError: function() {
            progressOuter.style.display = 'none';
            msgBox.innerHTML = 'Unable to upload file';
          }
    });
};
```

Full example: https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader/tree/master/examples/basic_example

I use Django 1.9 on the backend instead. And my frontend form looks like:

```
<form>{% csrf_token %}
...
</form>
```

Dgango tag `{% csrf_token %}` produces `<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='7CzH2kocMFDiGhSBlBY5OelS6oSND1Iw' />` for the page markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header is supposed to be called [`X-CSRFToken`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax) instead of `X-CSRF-TOKEN`.

If that doesn't work, try retrieving the token value from `csrftoken` cookie instead of the hidden input.

If that doesn't work, instead of setting the csrf header, can submit the token inside [`csrfmiddlewaretoken`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#how-it-works) post param, looks like your plugin supports passing extra params by using [`data`](https://www.lpology.com/code/ajaxuploader/docs.php) property.

Comment: You are right, the correct property name is `X-CSRFToken`. Thank you very much.